# Adding ActiveRecord on top of a Rails + Mongoid install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an existing project with Rails 5.2 and Mongoid 7, I had previously disabled all activerecord-related modules.

We are working on some synchronization with business intelligence data warehouses, and I discovered [this gem](https://github.com/customink/activerecord-aurora-serverless-adapter) that seems like a good starting point : I'm planning to use ActiveRecord with this adapter to easily implement code that will push data to my Amazon Aurora DB for BI purposes.

I have created a simple model

```
# model/test.rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have added a database.yml

```
# config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: aurora_serverless
  ...
```

But when I try to do anything with a model it says it could not connect

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection with pool with 'primary' found

Am I missing other things to make ActiveRecord work ? Do I need some additional Railties, etc ? It's as if the database.yml file was not read at all

Comment: Have you tried running `rails db:migrate:reset`?

Comment: hmm it seems that I was indeed missing the `require 'active_record/railtie'` in config/application.rb that is responsible for reading the database.yml file and configuring the ActiveRecord adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a summary of the things I ended up doing

- add required gems in your Gemfile (as a matter of fact, the gem I added did not even require the mysql2 gem which is quite a relief as mysql2 has dependencies on the local OS libs, and you're quite likely to encounter many bugs)
- create a `config/database.yml` file, and have one key per environment you need, with the AR config you need
- in application.rb, add `require 'active_record/railtie'` (the railtie will initialize connection from the database.yml file)
- create some models
- Maybe you need extra adapters for local/test/staging/prod environments
- Add a container for a SQL DB if you're working with docker-compose